# How to add a button in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development

I have a document library in that Folders and Sub folders are there. The folders are creating through code.

How to add button in each folder page to download multiple file at once using JavaScript or C#

[image: Click here to view the image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$(".ms-listview-qcbContainer ul.ms-qcb-leftzone ").append("<li class='ms-qcb-item'><input type='button' value='Your Button Name' class='hvr-grow-shadow' id='bt' onclick='getfiles()' style='border: 1px solid #0072c6;'></li>");
```

Hope It will work for you.